# 2 inputs at the same time can't be read

Tags: python, input

I am just starting with Python. When doing a tutorial I did exactly what the guy said, and in the beginning it worked, but then it didn't anymore. It is as if the first line becomes the input of the second input. (If I run each input line seperately it works though). I'm working on VSC.

```
name = input("What's your name?")
color = input("What's your favourt color?")
print(name + " likes the color " + color)

Output on VSC
>>> name = input("What's your name?")
What's your name?color = input("What's your favourt color?")
>>> print(name + " likes the color " + color)
color = input("What's your favourt color?") likes the color blue
```

Comment: Python error messages look differently; we have no idea where you enter what to get this; you'll need to be much more detailed, please! Generally, you say you're doing "a tutorial" – so link to it! That can never hurt!

Comment: Do you run the Python script from a file or do you copy paste the code into the python interpreter? It look like your are getting the error from that.

Comment: I am on Visual Studio Code. And in the beginning it worked and later (not changing anything) it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Use Formatted Output format like these:

```
name = input("What's your name?")
color = input("What's your favourt color?")
print(f"{name} likes the color {color}")
```